# How to Convert MySQL Date within MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have a query from within my vb.net code which searchs for a record by date. The date being entered via the code is in format dd/mm/yyyy, i need to search in the database using yyyy/mm/dd?

Ideally i thought there may just be a function within MySQL which will convert this. If not in vb.net to convert the string 01/01/2011 to 2011/01/01?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate? check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030407/convert-string-to-datetime-vb-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at str_to_date() function

```
select str_to_date('01/01/2011','%d/%m/%Y')
```

So, your search becomes

```
select * from table where date_field = str_to_date(your_variable,'%d/%m/%Y')
```