# Convert string to datetime in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, datetime

I have a datetime that looks like this:

```
201210120956
ccyyMMDDhhmm
```

When I try this:

```
Dim convertedDate As Date = Date.Parse(DateString)
Return convertedDate
```

I get back this:

```
#10/12/2012#
```

I'm losing the time on it.

I've read this [convert string to datetime vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030407/convert-string-to-datetime-vb-net) but when I use `datetime.ParseExact()` I get:

> cannot resolve symbol 'ParseExact'

Is there a way to convert this to a date time without using substring? A straight conversion?

Comment: Should be able to use ParseExact, it's been there since .net2 Waht about DateTime.Parse ?

Comment: Maybe I should just ask why ParseExact isn't being recognized.. seems noone saw that part of the post...

Comment: When I use DateTime.Parse() I get "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: I have no idea why visual studio wasn't seeing ParseExact but it is now and it's working...

Comment: I threw in DateTime.Parse just to see if it couldn't find that as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pass the decode pattern to ParseExact

```
Dim d as string = "201210120956"
Dim dt = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyyMMddhhmm", Nothing)
```

ParseExact is available **only** from Net FrameWork 2.0.
If you are still on 1.1 you could use Parse, but you need to provide the IFormatProvider adequate to your string

Comment: I've read this convert string to datetime vb.net but when I use datetime.ParseExact() I get:

    cannot resolve symbol 'ParseExact'

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact is a method of DateTime type present in the NET Framework from the version 2.0. Which version of the Framework are you using?

Comment: maybe since I went into the project properties it made it look again at my settings :P

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `ParseExact` method

Sample

```
Dim format As String  
format = "d" 
Dim provider As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
result = Date.ParseExact(DateString, format, provider)
```

Comment: I've read this convert string to datetime vb.net but when I use datetime.ParseExact() I get:

    cannot resolve symbol 'ParseExact'

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you put a space between the date and time, `DateTime.Parse` will recognize the format for you.  That's about as simple as you can get it. (If `ParseExact` was still not being recognized)